# Why isnt my GPA method calculating properly after passing it the correct parameters?

Tags: java, arrays, class, constructor

Hey everyone Im trying to solve this JAVA homework for class and Ive been stuck for the better part of the afternoon trying to get my GPA constructor to provide me the correct result.

I need the output to be the name of the student and its GPA. Currently the First Name and Last Name are being printed correctly but for the GPA Ive been getting Null and just right now I seem to be getting just a reference for it.

This is my main class code

```
package assignment2;

/**
*
* @author javyc
*/
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.HashSet;
public class Assignment2 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Classes[]courseArray = new Classes[2];
    courseArray[0] = new Classes("Javier", "Ruiz", "Winter 2018", 3);
    courseArray[1] = new Classes("Gabriela", "Ruiz", "Fall 2018", 3);

    double[] gpa = new double[2];
        gpa[0] = 4.00;
        gpa[1] = 4.00;

        Students ArizonaStudent = new Students("Javier", "Ruiz","MIS", "2020", courseArray, gpa);
        gpa = ArizonaStudent.getGpa();
        NumberFormat formatting = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        formatting.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

        System.out.println(ArizonaStudent.getStudentFirstName()+ " " + ArizonaStudent.getStudentLastName() + "" + gpa);
        //System.out.println(ArizonaStudent.getCourses(1));
}

}
```

This is my Student class code

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package assignment2;

/**
 *
 * @author javyc
*/
public class Students {
private String studentFirstName;
private String studentLastName;
private String department;
private String gradYear;

private Classes[] courses;
private double[] gpa1;

public Students(String studentFN, String studentLN, String dept, String graduationYear, Classes[]coursesList, double[]gpaList){
    studentFirstName = studentFN;
    studentLastName = studentLN;
    department = dept;
    gradYear = graduationYear;
    setCourses(coursesList);
    setGPA(gpaList);
}

public String getStudentFirstName(){
    return studentFirstName;
}
public String getStudentLastName(){
    return studentLastName;
}
public String getStudentDepartment(){
    return department;
}
public String getStudentGraduationYear(){
    return gradYear;
}
public Classes[]getCourses(){
    return courses;
}
public double[]getGpa(){
    return gpa1;
}


public void setStudentFirstName(String studentFN){
    studentFirstName = studentFN;
}
public void setStudentLastName(String studentLN){
    studentLastName = studentLN;
}
public void setDepartment(String department){
    this.department = department;
}
public void setGraduationYear(String gradYear){
    this.gradYear = gradYear;
}
public void setCourses(Classes[]courses){
    this.courses=courses;
}
public void setGPA(double[]gpa1){
    this.gpa1=gpa1;
}
 public class GPA{
public double gradePointAverage(){
    int totalCreds = 0;
    double gpaTotal = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i<courses.length;i++){
        totalCreds += courses[i].getCredits();
        gpaTotal += courses[i].getCredits()* gpa1[i];  
        return gpaTotal = gpaTotal/totalCreds;
    }
    return gpaTotal = gpaTotal/totalCreds;
}
}
}
```

This is my classes code

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project     Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package assignment2;

/**
 *
 * @author javyc
 */
public class Classes {
//We will start by declaring the attributes of the Classes offered at UA
private String professorFirstName;
private String professorLastName;
private String semesterOffered;
private int creditTotal = 0;

public Classes(String profMainName, String profLastName, String semester, int credits) 
    {
    professorFirstName = profMainName;
    professorLastName = profLastName;
    semesterOffered = semester;
    creditTotal = credits;
    }
public String returnFirstName(){
    return professorFirstName;
}
public String returnLastName(){
    return professorLastName;
}
public String returnSemester(){
    return semesterOffered;
}
public int getCredits(){
    return creditTotal;
}
public void establishedSemester(String semesterOffered){
    this.semesterOffered = semesterOffered;
}
public void establishFirstName(String professorFirstName){
    this.professorFirstName = professorFirstName;
}
public void establishLastName(String professorLastName){
    this.professorLastName = professorLastName;
}
public void establishCredits(Integer creditTotal){
    this.creditTotal = creditTotal;
}

}
```

Comment: Sorry I was editing the code into the post as you came in and saw it

Comment: How do you expect a GPA to be calculated if you never call `gradePointAverage()`?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple design issues.  I'm not sure what the original assignment requirements were, but is your class supposed to be Student or Students?  Student objects would then each represent a SINGLE student.  So, shouldn't that student just have a single GPA?

If you're setting the GPA for a student, I would assume you should pass the object's setGPA method a double, not a double array.  Does this make sense?

Comment: I believe it is just Student

Comment: So, it seems you should be using a single GPA instead of an array of doubles for each student, right?